# Divergence of $\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0} \frac{e^{\sec(x)}}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The question is to show that the following integral diverges $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0} \frac{e^{\sec(x)}}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx$$

My idea is to say: $\frac{e}{x^2} \leq \frac{e^{\sec(x)}}{x^2} \leq \frac{e^{\sqrt2}}{x^2} $
I can see that at it explodes at $x=0$, but I don't know where to go on from here.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0} \frac{e^{\sec(x)}}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx
\geq
\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0} \frac{e}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx =
\left.\frac{e\cdot x^{-1}}{-1}\right|_{x=\pi/4}-
\left.\underset{q\to 0^+}{\lim}\frac{e\cdot x^{-1}}{-1}\right|_{x=q} = \text{finite}-(-\infty)=\infty$$